# Linking storyboards elements to code

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

On one of the scenes in my storyboard, i placed a button. It shows on the view fine.

The view itself is represented by class `GameView`, which contains both

```
IBOutlet UIButton *b;

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIButton *b;
```

I have connected the outlet to button from the storyboard's view.

From `.m` file of the `GameView` class, i:

```
[[self b] setFrame:CGRectMake(420, 260, 50, 30)];
[b setTitle:@"!!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:[self b]];
```

When button is created programmatically, the following works fine

```
deal =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] ;
[deal setFrame:CGRectMake(420,170, 50, 30)];
[deal setTitle:@"Deal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self addSubview:[self deal]];
```

When program runs, however, the button from the storyboard is not seen. Why?

Comment: Doing `[self addSubview:[self b]];` is not necessary if the button already exists on the InterfaceBuilder storyboard.  That might actually be the problem, but Im not sure.  Try taking that line out and see what happens.

Comment: Good guess, but did it did not do it. Makes sense though

Comment: The `setFrame` for button `b` isnt necessary either unless your trying to move it from where you have it on the storyboard.  What happens when you do `NSLog(@"%@", self.b);` ?

Comment: In my case i do. But i thought of it as well. I used storyboards to drop elements in imprecise positions to later accurately place them inside the code

Comment: Also, have you `@synthesize b`?

Comment: I am a newb, but not that much of a newb :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an epic newb. Posting the answer in hopes someone else might find it useful.

Basically, in my case, the view is created programmatically from the controller, whatever is seen on the screen of a storyboard is effectively replaced on object creation.

```
UIView *gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300)];
[[self view] addSubview:gameView];
```

Once i put `IBOutlets` into the `Controller` and added

```
[bb setFrame:CGRectMake(420, 260, 50, 30)];
[bb setTitle:@"---" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[gameView addSubview:[self bb]];
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: So what fixed it exactly?  I don't see any difference in this code and the code in the question?

Comment: Instead of code being in `UIView` class i placed it into the `UIVIewController` and set frame dimentions before creating the view